# Simulated turtlebot dashboard problem

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new with ROS and Turtlebot. So I have very basic question. Should turtlebot dashboard work in simulated turtlebot. Because when I run:

```
rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard
```

Dashboard opens, but only the middle button under diagnostic is green. Others are gray. Also when I click on the "wrench" under Diagnostic I get info that everything is in Stale. Is this normal in simulated environment?

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28556/simulated-turtlebot-dashboard-problem/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The dashboard is not relevant for the simulation because we do not full simulate all of the physical hardware. You should not need the dashboard to use the TurtleBot simulator.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2012-02-26**:
Thank you for the tip. May I ask you something about the simulated kinect? Is it possible to get simulated raw image or create Point Cloud in Rviz with simulated Kinect "out of the box"? Because I can only get laser data posted on scan topic, but can't build Point Cloud.